# CLR type not serializable - C#

Tags: c#, .net

Without going into too much details, lets say I am trying to serialize parameters using:

```
tfsBuild.ProcessParameters = WorkflowHelpers.SerializeProcessParameters(process);
```

where process is a dictionary and one of the elements I am assigning is of the type:

```
IList<Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Changeset>
```

and `Changeset` is `public sealed`.

The `WorkflowHelpers.SerializeProcessParameters` fails with

```
Unable to serialize type 
'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Changeset'.
  Verify that the type is public and either has a default constructor 
or an instance descriptor.
```

since all types should be serializable.

Any thoughts/workarounds/ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some other custom class and include only the properties you need instead of `Changeset` which is not serializable. [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) could ease the conversion.

Comment: @Darin - I thought there could be a easy way :( Unfortunately, I can't use AutoMapper for this project, so I guess I need to do the manual mapping.

Comment: I am no aware of how the TFS API works but can't you serialize only some id and later reconstruct the changeset object from this id?

Comment: @Darin - Unfortunately, I am serializing this information and sending it to a activity which resides on a different TFS server and does not have access to do the reconstruction. By the way, I noticed that the Changeset has a ToString() method. I can send this as a string although I don't know how to the get IList from the string at the destination.

Comment: Not sure how to do XML serialization on a type that is not marked as Serializable. Is this still possible?

Comment: Of course, the `[Serializable]` attribute is used only for binary serialization and doesn't affect XML serialization.